How to allow (enforce) page-breaks for (inside) <iframe> elements?
Occasionally I want to print web pages which contain embedded long (high) <iframe> elements (into a pdf file).
Unfortunately these <iframe> elements never get cut when it is necessary.
Instead the top of <iframe> content is shifted to the next page.
All other stuff (like images or tables) are successfully cut (when necessary) but not <iframes>.
I tried a lot of CSS rules like
page-break-inside: auto !important;
or
break-inside: auto !important;
....but without any effect.
Is this a special problem for Firefox (on windows 10)?
How can I really, really enforce page-breaks even for <iframes>?
see above for description

Hmm, interesting. With which printer driver and which browser did you printed them on which OS?
